# IPad rotation: First rotation event is not notified?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, nsnotifications

My app design requires UIViews to be rotation aware.

When my app launches, it receives a `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`.

Then, however, at the very first rotation (either orientation to either orientation) no notification is received.

Every subsequent rotation event generates the expected `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notification.

The same applies to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notifications, when the code below is altered for device orientation checking - the results are identical.

The code:
(myUIView init)

```
// set up to listen for rotation
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(didRotate)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                             object:nil];
```

(myUIView on rotation)

```
-(void)didRotate
{

if ([self landscape])  // rotated TO landscape
    {
    // do landscape stuff
    }
}
```

(Rotation check in myUIView)

```
// answer the question: are we landscape?  Yes or no.  No indicates portrait.                                             
-(BOOL)landscape
{
  UIInterfaceOrientation iOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;  

// Just get a displayable string version
  NSString* iOrientationString ;
  switch (iOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait : iOrientationString = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" ; break ;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown : iOrientationString = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown" ; break ;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:iOrientationString = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft" ; break ;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:iOrientationString = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight " ; break ;
  }
  NSLog(@"%@=%@" , @S(iOrientation ) , iOrientationString ) ;



    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(iOrientation);
}
```

I note that in `UIViewController`, the `-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` is correctly called, first rotation and all.

But I would like to have rotation-aware views.  Is there an explanation, and/or a workaround for that missing first event?

Comment: put [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; into applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or put it into awakefromnib.

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or awakefromnib is either side of where it is (first line of my posted code.  Is that going to make such a huge difference?  Recall it IS (kind of) working - just missing the very first event.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went for a more 'normal'? solution, whereby I use `-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` in the `UIViewController` and have given up on the rotation-aware `UIView`.

Thanks for all the assistance.